# Rails session -- current_user changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a current_user variable set to the logged in user, this should be static for the duration of the session, but when I show one of the other users, I seem to "become" that user, with all of its permissions (or lack thereof)

in my users controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @user }
end
end
```

in my sessions helper:

```
  def current_user?(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

 def current_user
   @current_user ||= user_from_remember_token
 end
```

In my sidebar

```
<%= link_to current_user.username, :controller => 'users', :action => 'show', :id => current_user.id %></br>
```

This reflects the changing of the user (as does the new absence of additional "admin" links)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current_user?` method is incorrect. It sets the `current_user` to `user`, instead of returning whether `current_user` is the same as `user`.

If you change it to the following everything will probably work as expected:

```
def current_user?(user)
  @current_user == user
end
```

Comment: Sweet Moses, you guys are all fast - and good!  That did the trick!  Thanks mischa!  You've saved my forehead and desk much pounding....

Comment: Such an easy mistake to make. Good spotting!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your authentication system is storing the current user in both `@current_user` and `@user` -- so in your `show` action you are accidentally setting the current user to the user you are trying to show.

Try `@user_to_show` in your `show` action instead and see if that fixes it.